# Interactive Message Buttons not updating the web app

Tags: mattermost

I have implemented an Interactive Message Button and when pressed, the response is an update of the message.
In the Desktop app it works fine. But in the Browser I have to refresh to see the update. I think this is a bug because it does not make sense to update the post when the user does not see the update.

Comment: That's very strange. The desktop app is just an Electron wrapper around the web app. I would expect them to work the same, especially if you're testing in Chrome, since Electron is based on Chromium.

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading to Mattermost 4.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update problem got solved as we upgraded to Mattermost 4.4.3 .